# posting data from non-form elements

Tags: jquery, html, cakephp

Consider this dropdown:

[image: dropdown example]

Note that on selecting "new topic" an empty input box is dynamically added.

This is the html with css/class stripped:

```
<div id="form1">
    <div>
        <a>Select Topic</a>
        <div>
            <a>Create New Topic</a>
            <ul>
                <li>Topic 1</li>
                <li>Topic 1</li>
                <li>Topic 1</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Topic Name" style="display: inline-block;">
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Next">
        </div>
    </div> </div>
```

**Problem:**
As can be seen, a `<select>` tag has not been used inside a form to create the dropdown. I have to post/submit this data to my cakePhp controller. AFAIK, I have to get the div data through jquery, and do a jquery.post with the rest of the relevant data.

**Question:**
Am I correct to identify only jquery can be used to post this data, and not the usual simple post to controller method in cakePhp. Or is there any other way I'm missing? If yes, I have received many such forms. Is it better to rewrite all the forms as proper form elements (select tag) or write jquery to post all the "dirty forms" like this.

Comment: Couldn't you just create a hidden input in the form that you update the value with whenever the dropdown value changes?

Comment: As above, the correct way would be to have a hidden select input. In fact, your stylised select should really pull options from that hidden select as well. That's exactly how [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) does it.

Comment: Daniel & Christian, I received UI code like this, now I have to do something about it. They have used chosen only, so that solves my problem in some cases. But in other cases only divs have been used. As suggested by @Daniel, I will populate a hidden input for those cases. Thankyou, this should solve my problem.